# How to export original CSV columns, alongside Bigram count and frequency to new csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

This is one of my first times using Python so apologies if this is a silly question. I have a 3 column CSV, first column called comment (which is the column that I manipulated into bigrams), second column which is called comment type, and third column which is called comment date. I am satisfied with my current output from this code, where I split column 1 (Comment) into bigrams, counted the frequencies, and exported into a CSV file. But now I also want to add the comment type and comment date columns from my original csv (without making any changes to them) to my exported CSV next to word and frequency columns. I'm not to sure how to go about that and tested some ideas but didn't work.

```
import csv
import string
import re
from nltk.util import everygrams
import pandas as pd


from collections import Counter

from itertools import combinations

df = pd.read_csv('modified.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8",
                 names=['comment'])
top_N = 1000
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')

RE_stopwords = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(stopwords))

txt = df.comment.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ').str.cat(sep=' ')

words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(txt)
words = [w for w in words if not w in RE_stopwords]

bigrm = list(nltk.bigrams(words))



word_dist = nltk.FreqDist([' '.join(x) for x in bigrm])
rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),
                columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])

print(rslt)
rslt.to_csv('bigram3.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The added lines at the end, create a new column in your `rslt` dataframe, and copy the data from your original dataframe to this one.

```
import csv
import string
import re
from nltk.util import everygrams
import pandas as pd


from collections import Counter

from itertools import combinations

df = pd.read_csv('modified.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8",
                 names=['comment'])
top_N = 1000
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')

RE_stopwords = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(stopwords))

txt = df.comment.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ').str.cat(sep=' ')

words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(txt)
words = [w for w in words if not w in RE_stopwords]

bigrm = list(nltk.bigrams(words))



word_dist = nltk.FreqDist([' '.join(x) for x in bigrm])
rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),
                columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
rslt['Column_Type'] = df['comment type']
rslt['Column_Date'] = df['comment date']
print(rslt)
rslt.to_csv('bigram3.csv')
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: Thanks this was helpful! The rslt['Column_Type'] = df['comment type']
rslt['Column_Date'] = df['comment date'] is producing the desired results, but it is also creating two column headers in the CSV file when I only want one. How should I fix that?

Comment: Your column headers should be: index(unnamed), Bigram, Bigram Count, Comment_Type, and Column_Date. If you want to remove the unnamed index column, set `rslt.to_csv('bigram3.csv')` to `rslt.to_csv('bigram3.csv', index = False)`